# Manually Signing In Telethon Error telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.PhoneCodeExpiredError: The confirmation code has expired (caused by SignInRequest)

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am genreating a code using telethon's send request code method and then I use that code in telethon's sign in method i get-
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.PhoneCodeExpiredError: The confirmation code has expired (caused by SignInRequest)

telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.PhoneCodeExpiredError: The confirmation code has expired (caused by SignInRequest)

https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.auth.AuthMethods.sign_in

The above link is of telethon Sign in method. It says something about of obfuscating the code.How to do that?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)